# Sorting CSV entries using uasort()

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to sort each student entry by each student's GPA in a descending order. I've been tipped about `uasort()`, but I'm not sure what associative rules to create, seeing as I'm trying to sort an entire line, based on one entry.
My database is a CSV file (not ideal, but it's a requirement).

Here's my PHP code:

```
//Printing out details about each student in a table.
echo "<table border ='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo   "<th> Student ID </th>";
echo   "<th> First Name </th>";
echo   "<th> Last Name </th>";
echo   "<th> Birthdate </th>";
echo   "<th> Completed Courses </th>";
echo   "<th> Failed Courses </th>";
echo   "<th> GPA </th>";
echo   "<th> Status </th>";
echo "</tr>";
$data = file("../databases/students.csv");
foreach ($data as $line){
  $lineArray = explode(',', $line);
  list($studentID, $fName, $lName, $dob, $completedCourses, $failedCourses, $gpa, $status) = $lineArray;
  print <<< HERE
    <tr>
      <td> $studentID </td>
      <td> $fName </td>
      <td> $lName </td>
      <td> $dob </td>
      <td> $completedCourses </td>
      <td> $failedCourses </td>
      <td> $gpa </td>
      <td> $status </td>
    </tr>
HERE;
}
```

And here are my entries into the CSV file:
The entries are (Student ID, First Name, Last Name, D.O.B, Courses Completed, Courses failed, GPA, Status)

```
1, Emma, Zento, 07.03.97, 10, 2, 3.2, Honour,
2, Milo, Aniris, 04.12.02, 6, 0, 5, High Honour,
3, Akatsuki, Sato, 12.12.01, 3, 3, 2.1, Satisfactory,
4, Natsuki, Ito, 01.01.02, 6, 0, 4.0, High Honour,
```

Ideally it should be rendered like this with the help of the `uasort` function:

```
2, Milo, Aniris, 04.12.02, 6, 0, 5, High Honour,
4, Natsuki, Ito, 01.01.02, 6, 0, 4.0, High Honour,
1, Emma, Zento, 07.03.97, 10, 2, 3.2, Honour,
3, Akatsuki, Sato, 12.12.01, 3, 3, 2.1, Satisfactory,
```

Not sure if this is considered an open question, but I don't know where else to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to sort it before you output it, so you have to change the order you're doing things a bit. After you get the lines with `file()`, you can map `str_getcsv` over the lines to convert the strings to arrays.

```
$data = file("../databases/students.csv");
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', $data);
```

Then `$data` will be able to be sorted more easily. You can just use `usort`. `uasort` shouldn't be necessary for this because it doesn't look like the line indexes are meaningful. The associativity in `uasort` just means that the values (the lines) will stay associated with their keys (the 0-based index representing the line number). It isn't related to keeping the values inside each row associated with each other; sorting the main array won't affect that.

`6` should be the index of GPA, if I've counted correctly, and putting `$b` on the left-hand side of the comparison will make the sort descending.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $b[6] <=> $a[6];
});
```

Then your output code is basically the same as before, only the `explode` isn't necessary because the lines are already arrays.

```
foreach ($data as $line) {
  list($studentID, $fName, $lName, $dob, $completedCourses, $failedCourses, $gpa, $status) = $line;
  print <<< HERE
    <tr>
      <td> $studentID </td>
      <td> $fName </td>
      <td> $lName </td>
      <td> $dob </td>
      <td> $completedCourses </td>
      <td> $failedCourses </td>
      <td> $gpa </td>
      <td> $status </td>
    </tr>
HERE;
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! Exactly what i was looking for.